# colorful format for titles in documentation RI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

I am reading the book de Ruby of Pickaxe (ruby version  2.0) and I can not execute this statement

**$ export RI="--format ansi --width 70"**

I am using the native console of Ubuntu 12.04 and I have ruby within of RVM

Part of the book where the topic is explained

```
For general help on using ri, type ri --help. In particular, you might want to experiment with
the --format option, which tells ri how to render decorated text (such as section headings). If
your terminal program supports ANSI escape sequences, using --format=ansi will generate a
nice, colorful display. Once you find a set of options you like, you can set them into the RI
environment variable. Using our shell (zsh), this would be done using the following:
$ export RI="--format ansi --width 70"
```

My console. This looks bad 
ESC= ???

```
trabajo@fernando:~$ export RI="--format ansi --width 70" trabajo@fernando:~$ ri assoc

ESC[0mESC[1;32m.assocESC[m

(from ruby core) ESC[32mImplementation from ArrayESC[m
------------------------------------------------------------------------------   ary.assoc(obj)   -> new_ary  or  nil
```

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` variable in your shell?

Comment: The escape sequences are OK, but your terminal does not seem to interpret them correctly. Try to find out how to set your terminal to emulate xterm-color or xterm-256color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `TERM` environment variable is set correctly (either `xterm-color` or `xterm-256color` should suffice) it is most likely a problem with the pager used by `ri`

From the `ri` user manual:

> To use ANSI, either disable the pager or tell the pager to allow control characters.

So you have two options, really:

- disable the pager:

  `ri -T -f ansi assoc`
- use an ANSI-enabled pager, for instance `less -R`:

  `PAGER="less -R" ri -f ansi assoc`

You can either build the `-T` option into your `RI` environment variable, or else also export the `PAGER` environment variable in addition to the `RI` one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the [unix command `unset`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103555/how-do-i-unset-a-variable-at-the-command-line).

I ran into this same problem and just ran this:

`unset RI`

Then, if you run something like `ri GC` again it will have the default formatting.